# Jest Enzyme tesing, passing props as obj function and expect return for test

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have login component, and

MobileNumber as subComponent,

I am passing props details to the MobileComponent from LoginComponent

login.js

```
setHeaderInfo = () => {
    this.setState({
      showHeader: true,
      headerContent: {
        headerContent: {
         showBckBtn: true,
         headerTitle: 'Next'
        },
        headerTitle
      }
    })
  }
return(
<MobileComponent setHeaderInfo={this.setHeaderInfo}>
)
```

Now for testing js :

```
  let wrapper = shallow(<Login  />)

  const MobileNumberComponent = wrapper.find('MobileNumberComponent')

  it('header Title text checking', () => {
    MobileNumberComponent.props().setHeaderInfo( () => ({setHeaderInfo: {
      showHeader: true,
      headerContent: {
        showBckBtn: true,
        headerTitle: 'Next'
        }
    }}))
  })
```

Here console.log for

```
    console.log(MobileNumberComponent.debug())
<MobileNumberComponent setHeaderInfo={[Function]} />
```

I have passed the function here... But how could I expect that output... whether my test header is set or not as 'Next'..?

Answer (score 0):

After long hunting I found some solution to get into it..

Here I am using the connected component to render the element as props passing into it.

Here are the code:

```
import { mountWrap } from '../contextWrap'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import sinon from 'sinon'
import Login from '../components/Login/'
// import makeStore from '../redux/createStore'

import React from 'react'
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

const mockStore = configureMockStore([ thunk ])
const authDetails = {
  'authDetails' : {
    Terms :''
  }
}

const match = {
  params : {}
}
let actionSpy = sinon.spy()
let actionHistorySpy = sinon.stub({})
let authDetails_ = sinon.stub(authDetails)
let store
let component
/* eslint-disable */
describe('tests for MyContainerComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    store = mockStore(authDetails)
    component = mountWrap(<Provider store={ store }>
      <Login history={actionHistorySpy} match={match} setGlobalLoaderStatus= {actionSpy} userDetail={authDetails_} />
     </Provider>)
  })

  it('renders container', () => {
    console.log(component.debug())
  })
})
```

Yes, all we need to pass the mock data and store element as in route provider.